# SQL UDF Group By Parameter Issue

Tags: sql

I'm having some issues with a group by clause in SQL. I have the following basic function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetWinsYear (@Year int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  declare @W int
  select @W = count(1) 
    from tblGames 
    where WinLossForfeit = 'W' and datepart(yyyy,Date) = @Year
  return @W
END
```

I'm trying to run the following basic query:

```
select dbo.fn_GetWinsYear(datepart(yyyy,date)) 
from tblGames 
group by datepart(yyyy,date)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error message: *Column 'tblGames.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*.

Any ideas why this is occurring? FYI, I know I can remove the function and combine into one call but I'd like to keep the function in place if possible.

Comment: I don't recommend pursuing this approach.  You're thinking OOP in a SET based world; performance is not likely to scale well.

Comment: Yeah, I know this isn't ideal but I'm just trying to figure out why it's happening.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be calling your function like this.

```
select dbo.fn_GetWinsYear(datepart(yyyy,getdate()))
```

OR

```
select dbo.fn_GetWinsYear('2010')
```

Essentially you are just passing a year to your function and the function is returning the number of wins for that year.

If you don't know the year, your function could look something like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetWinsYear () 
RETURNS @tblResults TABLE
( W INT, Y INT )

AS 
BEGIN 

    INSERT @tblResults

    SELECT count(1), datepart(yyyy,[Date]) 
    FROM tblGames  
    WHERE WinLossForfeit = 'W'
    GROUP BY datepart(yyyy,[Date]) 


    RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetWinsYear()
```

Comment: That would work however I need to extract the year from the tblGames.Date column.

Comment: Since you already know the year, just add it to your query.
select dbo.fn_GetWinsYear(datepart(yyyy,getdate())), datepart(yyyy,getdate())

Comment: But I don't already know the year. It could be any year within the past X years.

Comment: (It should return 1 row for each year.)

Comment: @Germ, this provides a solution that would work. Thx for the help.